# `This` is undefined in vue.js watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have component with watcher

```
props: {
    propShow: { required: true, type: Boolean }
},

data() {
    return {
        show: this.propShow
    }
},

watch: {
    propShow: {
        handler: (val, oldVal) => {
            this.show = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever `parent` component changes `propShow` this component must update it's `show` property. `This` component also modifies `show` property, that's why I need both: `show` and `propShow`, because Vue.js does not allow to change properties directly.

This line

```
this.show = val;
```

causes error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'show' of undefined
```

because `this` inside handler is `undefined`.

Why?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You will have to use `function` syntax here, as warned in the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch):

> Note that you should not use an arrow function to define a watcher (e.g. searchQuery: newValue => this.updateAutocomplete(newValue)). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and this.updateAutocomplete will be undefined.

So your code should be:

```
watch: {
    propShow: {
        handler: function(val, oldVal) {
            this.show = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to write a setter for a singular, as in not derived out of other properties, computed property?

Comment: object's `handler` keyword can be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

"function" is not es6 code, you should better write:

```
watch: {
    propShow: {
        handler(val, oldVal) {
            this.show = val;
        }
    }
}
```